# Scaling fft2 after zeropad frequency domain

Tags: matlab, fft, padding, scaling

I have an image I1=(50x50) with two circles - A (which pixels have an intensity value of 100) and B (intensity values of 500).

I want to resize the image to I2=(100x100). I started by doing a FFT2 of the image, after that I zero padded it, making the FT a matrix of 100x100 and then doing the IFFT2 again.

```
FT = fftshift(fft2(M)); 
FT = padarray(FT,[50 50]);
I2 = ifft2(ifftshift(FT));
```

So now I have a new image with size 100x100 but now the amplitude for the circles is different. How do I correct this scaling problem?

After this I apply a mask to select only the circle A so I have now I3=(100x100) with only the circle A. To this image I am applying a FFT2 again and taking only the 50x50 part in the center of this FT and doing the IFFT2 to get another image PSF=(50x50) where I can see a point spread function (PSF) of this circle.

```
FT = fftshift(fft2(I3)); 
FTcenter = FT(25:75,25:75);
I4 = ifft2(ifftshift(FTcenter));
```

Again, should I apply any scaling here as well?

Comment: What do you mean by the "amplitude" of a circle?

Comment: @Suever I meant the intensity values of the pixels inside the circle

Answer (score 0):

I love using the built-in [`interpft`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interpft.html) for FFT-based sinc-interpolation because it takes all the legwork out of zero-padding, shifting, scaling, etc. (and you can inspect how it does it: `edit interpft`, it’s all legit). It only does 1D interpolation but you can run it twice in both dimensions for 2D.

I made a 100 by 100 grayscale image containing two circles, with min/max intensities [29, 255]:

[image: Start image]

Then, in the Matlab REPL:

```
>> im = double(imread('circles.png'));
>> whos im
  Name        Size             Bytes  Class    Attributes

  im        100x100            80000  double

>> imup = interpft(interpft(im, 2*size(im,1), 1), 2*size(im,2), 2);
>> whos imup
  Name        Size              Bytes  Class     Attributes

  imup      200x200            320000  double
```

This creates the 2× upsampled image. It’s min and max are [23.059, 271.66],  outside the bounds of the original [29, 255], so I rescale the values of the upscaled image to live in the same bounds as the original image, convert to `uint8`, and save it as PNG:

```
>> rescaled = interp1([min(imup(:)), max(imup(:))], [min(im(:)), max(im(:))], imup);
>> imwrite(uint8(rescaled), 'circles-up.png')
```

[image: upsampled]

Looking closely at this result, you can see why the min/max values of the upscaled array are broader than the original: this kind of sinc-interpolation causes [Gibbs ringing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringing_artifacts) at sharp transitions in the image like the circle edges, which causes the upscaled image to overshoot peaks and undershoot troughs.

---

`interpft` can both interpolate (upsample) as well as decimate (downsample). So here’s a complete script—with one tweak: I “invert” the colors from my original image so the background is black instead of white: this makes masking easier:

```
clearvars
interpft2 = @(x, sz) interpft(interpft(x, sz(1), 1), sz(2), 2);

im = 255 - double(imread('circles.png'));
imup = interpft2(im, 2*size(im));

mask = double(imread('circles-mask.png')) ~= 255;
psf = interpft2(mask .* imup, round(size(imup) / 2));
imwrite(uint8(255 - round(psf)), 'psf.png')
```

Here is the upsampled `circles-mask.png` mask (where black means data to *keep*):

[image: mask]

And here's the resulting `psf` image (inverted), which is the same as the original `circles.png` image without the little circle:

[image: point spread function]

It appears that, because of linearity, applying the mask in the 2× upsampled image is equivalent to just applying a smaller mask in the original image.

So I should ask if what I did above match what you’re trying to do with the PSF? I’d like to again emphasize that the interpolating and decimating steps you describe in your question (FFT→zeropad→IFFT and FFT→keep center→IFFT) are *exactly* what `interpft` does (plus the bookkeeping to make sure amplitudes and symmetries are correct).

Comment: But the Gibbs ringing is what I am looking for in the end. I want that information basically.

Comment: Yup, so there you 

Comment: But I wanted to simulate the ringing effect you get when you use only a fraction of your whole kspace. That's why I was going back to a smaller matrix again @AhmedFasih

Comment: I’m very sorry, I didn’t read the second part of your question where you talk about PSF. Hmmm—`interpft` can both interpolate *and* decimate (in the latter case, it does exactly what you describe: take FFT, keep only the low frequencies, and IFFT, along with the bookkeeping for correct scaling, symmetry, etc.), so you could do `I4 = interpft2(interpft2(I2 .* mask, 100, 1), 100, 2)`. However, what is the purpose of this? By linearity, applying the mask on `I2` is equivalent to applying it on `I`, so `I4` will, in this example, just be the original image containing Circle A.

Comment: See my edited answer for a more complete discussion of this.